# Ubuntu can't locate module-assistant

Tags: software-installation, repository

So, I insert this code into ubuntu,

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms module-assistant
```

And it displays the error

```
E: Unable to locate package module-assistant
```

Do you know how to deal with this (Ubuntu 18.04.1)?

Comment: Do you have the universe repo enabled?

Comment: Also, have you run `apt-get update`?